# Seaborn Barplot labeling with Inconsistent Hue position

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

Good Morning,

I have been struggling with labeling the categorical 'hues' to a seaborn barplot.
The code I have works if there are data points for each position on the x-axis, but I get an error from  (height = rect.get_height()) as the first rect position shows a NaN value.  I am not sure how to 'offset' to the next rect where there is a value.

Here is sample df:

```
    Procedure    plan_cat Region      Fees  Referrals
0           9   InNetwork      a  0.178155         44
1          92   InNetwork      a  1.491056          1
2           9   InNetwork      b  0.249290         45
3          92   InNetwork      b  1.491000          2
4           9   InNetwork      c  0.250906        105
5          92   InNetwork      c  1.490889          2
6           9   InNetwork      d  0.316211         63
7          92   InNetwork      d  1.491000          3
8           9   InNetwork      e  0.300000         29
9          92   InNetwork      e  1.491000          4
10          9   InNetwork      f  0.300000         24
11         92   InNetwork      f  1.491000          5
12          9  Specialist      a  0.433522          6
13         89  Specialist      a  1.481618          6
14          9  Specialist      b  0.594962          2
15         89  Specialist      b  1.487511          9
16          9  Specialist      c  0.879057          6
17         89  Specialist      c  1.484376         25
18          9  Specialist      d  1.153279          8
19         89  Specialist      d  1.467492         22
20          9  Specialist      e  1.009909          6
21         89  Specialist      e  1.495741         11
22         92  Specialist      e  1.736217          2
23          9  Specialist      f  1.568886         10
24         89  Specialist      f  1.683757         22
```

I just learned the pd.read_clipboard trick,  select the full df with cursor and ctrl+c  and follow along.

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

df['plan_cat']=df['plan_cat'].astype('category')

for prod in set(df['Procedure']):
    deef = df[df['Procedure']==prod]  
    deef.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
    a4_dims = (11.7, 8.27)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=a4_dims)
    gr=sns.barplot( x='Region' , y='Referrals', data=deef,ci=0  , hue='plan_cat'
                   ,ax=ax ,saturation=.6, alpha=.5,hue_order=['InNetwork','Specialist'])                    
    gr.axes.set_title("Procedure "+str(prod),fontsize=25)
    gr.set_xlabel("Region Code",fontsize=15)
    gr.set_ylabel("Referrals",fontsize=15)
    gr.tick_params(labelsize=10)
    rects = gr.patches
    for rect, label in zip(rects,deef['Fees']):
        height = rect.get_height()
        if np.isnan(height):
            continue
        gr.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2, height+0.2,str(round(label,2)), 
                color='black',
                ha="center",fontweight='bold')
```

The graph of procedure 9 looks exactly as planned.

[image: good]

However, if 'InNetwork' is missing as in procedure 89 or 'Specialist' doesn't follow in perfect sequence starting at 'a'  labeling gets out of whack or omitted.

[image: bad]
[image: bad 2]

I've fooled around with printed rect.height, rect.get_x in loops to see how they are being positioned and it is not making sense why the 1 'Specialist' in procedure 92 is visually showing up in 'e' region but rect is at 0?

Anyways, thanks for all the help.

My comment in code view:

```
for rect, label in zip(rects,deef['Fees']):
    print(str(round(rect.get_x(),1))+':'+str(rect.get_height()))

-0.4:1.0
0.6:2.0
1.6:2.0
2.6:3.0
3.6:4.0
4.6:5.0
0.0:nan
```

Comment: Not overly relevant to your question but doing `for prod in set(df['Procedure'])` isn't great pandas syntax - you can much more easily do `for proc, data in df.groupby('Procedure')` and have direct access to the data relating to that procedure.

Comment: Unless you have the labels grouped in a similar fashion as the bars, the approach is not successful. I see two options: (1) Group the labels in the same order as the bars appear in the graph, (2) use matplotlib to create the bar graph in which case you'd know already the order of bars.

Comment: Well, that's where I am confused if I print the coordinates of Procedure 92 rects using the line of code:    for rect, label in zip(rects,deef['Fees']):
    print(str(round(rect.get_x(),1))+':'+str(rect.get_height())) it returns
-0.4:1.0
0.6:2.0
1.6:2.0
2.6:3.0
3.6:4.0
4.6:5.0
0.0:nan       so it is grouping by 'InNetwork' first and 'Specialist' second which is how I custom sorted the df.  I just don't understand why the last rect (Only 'Specialist' in the case of 92) is showing a (x,y) coordinate of (0,nan) when clearly the visualization shows otherwise

Comment: I edited post with code for better readability